# How to know which view the user touches on screen

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, touch

If there is a uiscrollview and and multiple sub view on the uiscrollview. how to know where the user touches i.e on specific view or scrollview(blank space)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 possibilities for detect the touch with `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;` in a scrollView:

first, implement this method in your viewController, and add the scrollview on this viewController.

second, which I recommend: make a custom class which is inherited from UIScrollView like this:
.h:

```
@interface CustomScrollView : UIScrollView 

@end
```

.m:

```
#import "CustomScrollView.h"


@implementation CustomScrollView

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    if(!self.dragging){
        [self.nextResponder touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self.nextResponder touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}

@end
```

in your vc make:

...

```
CustomScrollView* customScrollView = [[CustomScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
```

...

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        NSLog(@"View touched: %@", touch.view);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this approach:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        NSLog(@"View touched: %@", touch.view);
}
```

This method is called every time your finger touches the screen, and the touch knows which view it touched.

Edit: It won't work on a UIScrollView because the scroll view gets the touch itself, check this:

[touchesBegan method not called when scrolling in UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971819/touchesbegan-method-not-called-when-scrolling-in-uiscrollview)

[How to enable touch began in UIScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386840/how-to-enable-touch-began-in-uiscrollview)

Comment: but it is not getting called when we use scrollview and add sub view to scroll view

Comment: Is there any option to detect the touches on scrollview

Comment: That method should be triggered whatever it is on the screen.

Comment: You have to implement this method on the superView, for example self.view

Comment: It is not getting called if the base view is scroll view

Comment: USe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386840/how-to-enable-touch-began-in-uiscrollview or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971819/touchesbegan-method-not-called-when-scrolling-in-uiscrollview

Comment: I added a solution to you